# Ubuntu 20.04 64BIT For Raspberry Pi Zero 2

Tags: raspberrypi

This was supposed to be out at the beginning of the month.  Anyone have any ideas when this will actually release?

Answer (score 2):

According to the official download page for Raspberry Pi Images, the Raspberry Pi Zero 2 is compatible with 32-bit images.

See:

[Install Ubuntu on a Raspberry Pi](https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi)

[image]

Comment: @ the Bottom -- https://ubuntu.com/blog/raspberry-pi-zero-2-w-with-ubuntu-server-support-is-here

Answer (score 0):

I got it to boot Ubuntu 20.04 arm64 using the instructions at https://waldorf.waveform.org.uk/2021/the-pi-zero-2.html and the comment about `uboot_rpi_3.bin`.

In summary, you have to:

1. copy the device tree file `cp bcm2710-rpi-3-b.dtb bcm2710-rpi-zero-2.dtb`
2. skip uboot by adding

```
[pi0]
kernel=uboot_rpi_3.bin
```

after [pi3] in the `config.txt`.