# Onboard WLAN drivers for RPi Zero 2 W running Ubuntu Server 20.04.3 64-bit

Tags: server, 20.04, wireless, 64-bit

Rpi Zero 2 W finally arrived, managed to get 20.04.3 64-bit booted after doing the RPi3 [udate & upgrade dance](https://waldorf.waveform.org.uk/2021/the-pi-zero-2.html) by adding:

```
[pi0]

kernel=uboot_rpi_3.bin
```

after [Pi3] in the config.txt as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1376197/ubuntu-20-04-64bit-for-raspberry-pi-zero-2)

Stuck getting onboard Wi-Fi working although a Pi USB dongle works OK.  Basically `rfkill list all` doesn't show anything, should list WLAN0 which it does if I insert a USB Wi-Fi dongle.

Tried adding drivers as suggested [here](https://gitlab.alpinelinux.org/alpine/aports/-/issues/13302) but didn't work for me:-(

Need 20.04 64-bit for an ROS project, would be SWEET to have it running on the Zero 2.  Can work around with the USB Dongle Wi-Fi for now but it would sure be nice to have onboard Wi-Fi...

Edit as requested below, CLI command`sudo dmesg | grep -i sdio` yields:

```
[   19.255552] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac43430-sdio for chip BCM43430/1

[   19.321864] brcmfmac mmc1:0001:1: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43430-sdio.raspberrypi,model-zero-2.txt failed with error -2

[   19.321990] brcmfmac mmc1:0001:1: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43430-sdio.txt failed with error -2

[   20.328472] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_htclk: HT Avail timeout (1000000): clkctl 0x50
```

Worked around this issue for awhile with a [cana kit wifi dongle](https://www.canakit.com/raspberry-pi-wifi.html) but really need the onboard wifi now to get rid of the giant (relativeley speaking:-) USB hub.

So, per below I tried following after wget [this file](https://github.com/openwrt/cypress-nvram/blob/master/brcmfmac43430-sdio.raspberrypi%2Cmodel-zero-w.txt) and here are the results.  If I remove the wifi dongle (and reboot) there is still no wlan0.

`sudo cp brcmfmac43430-sdio.raspberrypi,model-zero-w.txt brcmfmac43430-sdio.raspberrypi,model-zero-2.txt`
`sudo dmesg | grep brcm`

```
[   18.849187] brcmfmac: F1 signature read @0x18000000=0x1541a9a6
[   18.863213] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac43430-sdio for chip BCM43430/1
[   18.876023] usbcore: registered new interface driver brcmfmac
[   20.075000] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_htclk: HT Avail timeout (1000000): clkctl 0x50
[   21.087395] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_htclk: HT Avail timeout (1000000): clkctl 0x50
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `sudo dmesg | grep -i sdio` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks, please see edit.  Way over my head:-/

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
cd /usr/lib/firmware/brcm
sudo wget https://github.com/openwrt/cypress-nvram/blob/master/brcmfmac43430-sdio.txt
```

Reboot and let us see:

```
sudo dmesg | grep brcm
```

**EDIT**: The message log still shows that the device wants the firmware file brcm/brcmfmac43430-sdio.raspberrypi,model-zero-2.txt. A thorough internet search finds no such file. I suggest that we rename a similar file to see if it helps.

```
cd /usr/lib/firmware/brcm
sudo cp brcmfmac43430-sdio.raspberrypi,model-zero-w.txt brcmfmac43430-sdio.raspberrypi,model-zero-2.txt
```

Reboot and again edit your question to show:

```
sudo dmesg | grep brcm
```

Comment: See edit thanks also for the format help:-/

Comment: Updated still no wlan0 without usb dongle, please see edit...

Comment: I regret that I have no further suggestions. I assume the correct firmware will be published sometime soon. Sorry.